# How can I set minute intervals for bootstrap clock picker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, clock, picker

Is is possible to set minute intervals for [bootstrap clock picker](http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/) (not time picker)?

For example 5 minutes, 15 minutes, 30 minutes?

Comment: Did you find any solutions to this ? I also want to set interval for minutes.

Comment: I guess that didn't get your point, you wanna handle some function when you get 5, 15 or 30 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question but I wanted to know the solution. It's not implemented yet as configurable, but you can code it and it will work as the attached image.

**Make minute interval configurable #32** Go to [this git](https://github.com/weareoutman/clockpicker/pull/32/commits/0b6d7c47276266cac1d3918719b76bf349b68d02).

commit the changes and change this line:

```
this.minuteInterval = 15; // 10, 15 or 30
```

[image: Demo]